# Cannot open Document library by WebDAV URL LifeRay 7

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I'm a newbie in LifeRay, explain me please why I cannot map new network drive using WebDAV URL.

My WebDAV URL: http://liferay-portal.liferay.local/webdav/informacionnyj-fond/document_library

Error Message: The folder you entered doesn't appear to be valid. Please choose another.

My environment: Windows Server 2012 R2, TomCat 8.0.32, LifeRay 7

Need I configurate something in TomCat or something else?